# A TypeScript Issue: the parameters of a function are different from what is expected theoretically

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code, I expected `bike({name:"bike"})`, but it's throwing an error. I don't know why it's behaving this way.

```js
const crateBox = <BikeData, CarData>()=>{

    const bike = (data:BikeData)=>{
        console.log("bike data: ", data);
    }

    const car = (data:CarData)=> {
        console.log("car data: ", data);
    }

    return [bike, car];
}


const [bike, car] = crateBox<{name:string}, {type:string}>();

bike({name:"bike"})
```

The Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBDKBTAQiAHjAvDAPGgJYDWKAIsogDQwDCi8lUiAfABQCUOrA3gFD8YwuOGgwARqRS4Y7ACZUAXMTLNE3PkJE7QkEABsUAOgMgA5uwBEUsjEUslMK7QcaA3NuEBfQbrGwwIyyCsoMTFSaMAI6-vpGphbWQfD2ys6ukZ46vl4w8ChQAK7wYDAA2rYotCkAup65-HrildI1jLWyCMjoWPi8YIgAtihK0PBEYObetLxQAJ4ADqPjk9McnJ78VewDw6M20lbenEA

[image]

But if I change `const [bike, car] = createBox<{name:string}, {type:string}>();` to `const {bike, car} = createBox<{name:string}, {type:string}>();`, it works correctly. However, I want to use the format `[bike, car]` and not encounter an error.

How to solve this problem?

```js
const crateBox = <BikeData, CarData>()=>{

    const bike = (data:BikeData)=>{
        console.log("bike data: ", data);
    }

    const car = (data:CarData)=> {
        console.log("car data: ", data);
    }

    return {bike, car};
}


const {bike, car} = crateBox<{name:string}, {type:string}>();

bike({name:"bike"})
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBDKBTAQiAHjAvDAPGgJYDWKAIsogDQwDCi8lUiAfABQCUOrA3gFD8YwuOGgwARqRS4Y7ACZUAXMTLNE3PkJE7QkEABsUAOgMgA5uwBEUsjEUslMK7QcaA3NuEBfQbrGwwIyyCsoMTFSaMAI6-vpGphbWQfD2ys6ukZ46vl4w8ChQAK7wYNG2KLQp3p65-HrivBVVjN6yCMjoWPi8YIgAtihK0PBEYObetLxQAJ4ADkMjYxMcnJ78Fey9A0M20lbenEA

Comment: (Aside: `K` as a type parameter conventionally implies a keylike type; it's not just "the next thing after `T`". It is more conventional to use `U` instead of `K` in such circumstances; could you please [edit] to change that so it's not distracting?) Array literals like `[bike, car]` tend to be inferred as unordered arrays. If you don't like that you can use a const assertion, `[bike, car] as const`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxzK8w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, problem solved. I just started learning TypeScript. Why is this happening?

Comment: *Which* problem is solved? Why is *what* happening?  I'm confused by your response. Could you clarify?

Comment: `[bike, car] as const` helped me resolve the issue. Without adding `as const`, I always received an error when using `bike({name:"bike"})`: Argument of type `'{ name: string; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'{ name: string; } & { type: string; }'`. Property `'type'` is missing in type `'{ name: string; }'` but required in type `'{ type: string; }'`.
Thanks.

Comment: So then if I write up an actual answer explaining what's happening, there's a good chance it will be acceptable to you?

Comment: I learn about TypeScript and as const through YouTube videos. Although I still don't fully understand it, I know how to address such issues the next time they arise. Perhaps my experience and knowledge are limited, but I am determined to improve and learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of `crateBox()`, TypeScript [*infers*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) the type from the value you returned, which was the [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) `[bike, car]`.  Type inference relies on heuristic rules to choose the most appropriate type.  For array literals, the compiler assumes that the developer wants a plain [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays), which represents an unordered list of arbitrary length.  People often modify arrays by adding elements to them, removing elements from them, or reordering them.  So this is a reasonable assumption.

But that means `[bike, car]` is inferred as type `(((data: BikeData) => void) | ((data: CarData) => void))[]`.  So all the compiler keeps track of is that each element of that array is either a `BikeData` consumer or a `CarData` consumer. It doesn't know the locations of them in the array or how long the array is.

That doesn't meet your needs. The assumption that you wanted an unordered arbitrary-length array type was incorrect.

---

What you apparently want is for the return type of `crateBox()` to be a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  A tuple type is an array whose length and types of elements at each position are known and fixed.  In your case, it would look like the type `[(data: BikeData) => void, (data: CarData) => void]`, an array of length 2, whose first element is a `BikeData` consumer, and whose send element is a `CarData` consumer.

Now, you *could* just annotate the return type and give up entirely on inference:

```
const crateBox =
    <BikeData, CarData>(): [(data: BikeData) => void, (data: CarData) => void] => {
        // ------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        const bike = (data: BikeData) => { console.log("bike data: ", data); }
        const car = (data: CarData) => { console.log("car data: ", data); }
        return [bike, car]; // okay
    }

const [bike, car] = crateBox<{ name: string }, { type: string }>();   
bike({ name: "bike" }); // okay
```

That works inside the function because now the compiler knows the exact type you wanted, and it can verify that `[bike, car]` matches that type.  And it works outside the function because now the type of `bike` is the first element of the tuple type, and thus `(data: { name: string }) => void`.

---

But you don't need to go that far. Instead you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the `[bike, car]` expression you're returning.  This still uses type inference, but it tells the compiler that you really want it to pay attention to the exact literal value; array literals should be given tuple types, and other primitive literals should be given [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  If you do that:

```
const crateBox = <BikeData, CarData>() => {    
    const bike = (data: BikeData) => { console.log("bike data: ", data); }    
    const car = (data: CarData) => { console.log("car data: ", data); }    
    return [bike, car] as const;
}
```

Now the return type of `crateBox` is `readonly [(data: BikeData) => void, (data: CarData) => void]`.  This is a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) which isn't known to have mutating methods like `push()` or `sort()`, and won't let you reassign the values.  But otherwise it's the same as the annotated tuple type `[(data: BikeData) => void, (data: CarData) => void]` from the previous section.

And that means the compiler will know that the first element of the returned array is a `BikeData` consumer, and the second is a `CarData` consumer, and thus you get the behavior you want with minimal changes to your code:

```
const [bike, car] = crateBox<{ name: string }, { type: string }>();
bike({ name: "bike" }); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBDKBTAQiAHgeXgSwHMYBeGAHjTwGsUARZRAGhgGFF56pEA+ACgEoS3GAG8AUGJhS44aDABG1FCRi8AJgwBcMSjU6JBxYeOmmZkEABsUAOksgCvAESKaMDV21PmHgwG5JaQBfCVNQSFhgdhV1LVZ2fUNjQLNzCCtbe0cnKPh3OO98rn4A0xCUmHgUKABXeDAYAG1XFGZcgF0AkIB6ACo0yKRUDBx8Am0KJX1mNg4GPiTVXljPHSmGRYA3EDw1QQAfJd9tWcShGG3d-n5G9phe7okxcLkEZHQsAEEwH5AuVBIFUmegYMwS8wE2kaK0Q2l0dA250uamYMJO4OKSJ2ajuRlEFVM3W6MAAtGTyRSycIAHq0un0hmMpnMlnMgnSF6wFoxY5rEGYvEiNIZOwOZzc3mFXwlGAhVJSTlwaKkNHxOYC4zC6yi7K5IqwmBSjZ+WXsqRVWr1JotNrsToVcqKt7DLAqYEIrhg9U8ATncQVRXclW8+FnQVmrWZMUuJT6rw+Y0O0Ic2SRZWqXmnRHh+WRnXOPWShPFUrBZPm6p1BrNJS2+B3RAQAZdMR9AZwIYfTATUOgtX6BbnZaq3sai7Yg5HOJZsfI663e6PNtOzsjHvrT39iGLKqINTgSwATyaI43Bixu1RmYx57xyLuDwkiprNDruI77xGZCFYEQAFsUG0aB8DAIggmYIUoEPAAHQCYGAvBQNlBYAjEFpeB-f84JjGgnFlfggA)